# How to get the Current Height and Width of the Browser

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How can I get the Height and Width of the Browswer .

I tried using :

```
double Width = (double)HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.availWidth");
double Height = (double)HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.availHeight");
```

But this Returns the Current Screen Resolution. But I  need to handle Some Controls like Media Element Height and Width When the User Restore the browser or let say  resize the browser by clicking on the edge and resizing it.

So again the buttom line is I want the the Height and width of the broswer , not the current System resolution.

Thanks,

Subhen